# Can not install package 'swirl' on my rstudio

Tags: r, swirl

I have a problem to install package 'swirl' on my Rstudio. I tried several cran in China and it cannot connect to server every time. Does anyone know any possible reason? *ps:since the stackoverflow does not allow me to post more than one URL link so I cut off a 'h' of from 'http'

```
 install.packages("swirl")
```

Warning in install.packages :

> URL
>   'http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds':
>   status was 'Couldn't connect to server' Warning in install.packages : 
>   URL 'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz':
>   status was 'Couldn't connect to server' Warning in install.packages : 
>   URL 'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES':
>   status was 'Couldn't connect to server' Warning in install.packages : 
>   unable to access index for repository
>   ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib:   cannot open URL
>   'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES' Warning
>   in install.packages :   URL
>   'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds':
>   status was 'Couldn't connect to server' Warning in install.packages : 
>   URL 'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz':
>   status was 'Couldn't connect to server' Warning in install.packages : 
>   URL 'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES':
>   status was 'Couldn't connect to server' Warning in install.packages : 
>   unable to access index for repository
>   ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib:   cannot open URL
>   'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/PACKAGES' Warning
>   in install.packages :   package 'swirl' is not available (for R
>   version 3.4.0) Warning in install.packages :   URL
>   'ttp://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds':
>   status was 'Couldn't connect to server'

Comment: Have you tried another mirror?

Comment: yes, I have tried several mirror but it all not works

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
install.packages("swirl", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: If you could add some information about why the proposed solution answers the question that will make the contribution more valuable for the site...